Is it possible to reduce cache miss when visiting a large size vector in sequence?
I tring reduce cache miss when visiting a large array in sequence. The array size is about 10 million. I do not know if it is possible to reduce cache miss as much as possible ?
There are two arrays: one is raw array loaded from data file (ds_append_), another(ds_) will updated from the first. Sample data type define as follow:
/**
 * @brief Raw sample data structure which loads from the file.
 */
struct sample_data_app_t {
  point_double_t sample_data_{};  //!< sample data's raw data.
  int32_t cid_{};                 //!< sample data's Channel's ID.
  int32_t dbg_blk_id_{-1}, sid_{};
};

/**
 * @brief Sample data structure.
 * @details Sample data structure contains sample point readed from the file,
 * mapped-xy calculated by the R/W configures, and display-xy calculated by the
 * chart configures. @see ch_config_t
 */
struct sample_data_t {
  int32_t cid_{};                //!< sample data's Channel's ID (0 ~ 8).
  point_double_t mapped_pos_{};  //!< sample data's mapped position.
  sample_data_app_t* aptr_{};    //!< sample data's append pointer.
};

/**
 * @brief Sample dataset structure.
 * @details Sample dataset structure contains a vector of sample data.
 */
struct sample_dataset_t {
  std::vector<sample_data_t> ds_;                   //!< sample dataset's sample data vector.
  std::shared_ptr<sample_data_app_t[]> ds_append_;  //!< sample dataset's sample data append vector.
  size_t array_size_{0};                            //!< sample dataset's sample data array size.
};

the following code snippet response for update ds_ from ds_append_:
  auto update_func = [&](sample_data_t& sample) {
      const auto cid = sample.cid_; // channel index 0 ~ 8
      const auto& ch_config = chConfigs[cid];
      const auto& sample_range = sampleDataConfig.ch_limits_[cid];

      const auto ax = sample.aptr_->sample_data_.x_;
      const auto ay = sample.aptr_->sample_data_.y_;

      const auto slen = sample_range.y_max_ - sample_range.y_min_;
      const auto ys = (ay - sample_range.y_min_) * 256.0 / slen;

      const double yy1 = std::abs(ch_config.max_spc_) * ch_config.cos_x_ * ys / 256.0;
      const double mapped_y = ch_config.os_y_ + yy1 * ch_config.scale_y_;

      const double mapped_x = ch_config.os_x_ + ax * ch_config.unit_scale_x_;
      sample.mapped_pos_ = {mapped_x, mapped_y};
    };

    const auto data_num = ds.ds_.size();
    const auto thd_num = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    if (data_num > kParallelThreshold) {
      tbb::parallel_for(
        tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0, data_num, data_num / thd_num),
        [&](const tbb::blocked_range<size_t>& r) {
          for (size_t i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); i++) {
            update_func(ds.ds_[i]);
          }
        },
        tbb::static_partitioner{});
    } else {
      std::for_each(ds.ds_.begin(), ds.ds_.end(), update_func);
    }


Note1: The cid is randomly from 0 to 8 for each sample;
Note2: length of chConfigs[] and sampleDataConfig.ch_limits_[] is 9.

There's some memory bound in the test. One of these is
const auto cid = sample.cid_; // channel index 0 ~ 8
const auto& ch_config = chConfigs[cid];
const auto& sample_range = sampleDataConfig.ch_limits_[cid];


I'm confused why the address update instruction lea (%r8, %r8, 2), %r8 take so high memory bound ?
The test code repo: github -- perf_tests -- test_array_update

A vector stores all its data contiguously, like an array. If you iterate over all elements of the vector, in order from lowest to highest, you have already reduced cache-misses to a minimum. But that's only for single-threaded programs. If multiple threads iterates over individual parts of the vector, there will likely be more cache misses as the threads are preempted and restarted byt the OS.

When iterating over a vector (contiguous memory) the CPU can predict your memory access pattern very well and will prefetch data into your caches. You might be able to optimize this a bit by setting thread affinity to a specific core

Thanks Pepijin and dude. I start tbb::parallel_for with static_partitioner and each thread take sample_num / core_num samples (for my Intel CPU i5-8260U the core number is 8). I've not try using affinity_partitioner yet. I'll try it soon.

You can chunk the vector into cach size blocks, then run parallel code on chunks of each block, then you need a latch for your threads to wait for everyone to arrive and continue on next block. Simple division of data between threads doesn't work. In order to fool OS scheduler, you need more effort: data must be on shared memory, and multiple processes operate on it; that way you can steal more time from the OS.

At some point (unless you are doing a significant amount of work on each vector element) the code will saturate the memory bus.  This is possible with only a single thread.

Thanks @Red.Wave, I'm not familiar with TBB much (How to set chunk size ?). I'll try later after some more study. Or please can you give a sample code if possible ?
Question about your suggestions is: Why multiple process operate on a process shared vector will fool OS to get more run time?

@roderick that's a general solution. I am not into TBB either. But you can chunk the vector before entering the loop(maybe std::views::chunk). The more important problem is how to set a latch for TBB: does std::latch or std::barrier work? Or TBB has its own counterparts.

One option is to tune it to be cache aware of the larger L2 and L3 caches so that as few operations as possible access main memory directly. There is an interesting asymmetry between reads and writes in this respect. AOTBE writes benefit from being sequential to the same cache line because of clever hardware cache buffering (or put another way random scatter gun writes put a serious load on the cache system).

Silly answer: make your update_func slower, so hardware prefetch will be able to keep up.  Then the actual loads will hit in cache when they happen, so cache miss counts will be lower.  Real answer: like Martin suggested, cache-block for L2 size if you can.  If you can do more work in a single pass over your data (higher computational intensity: amount of work per time data gets into registers or into L1d cache), that helps.

Thanks to @PeterCordes and Martin for the suggestion to perform more calculations on a single data load, which is a great approach for common programming practices. After re-examining the code, I couldn't find any further opportunities to optimize the sample function.

I just ran this code through a profiler, your code is hitting the max DRAM bandwidth, for example 30 GB/s on this machine, DRAM sticks do have a limit to how much data they can transfer per second.
The most obvious solution is to throw money at the problem and use a computer with more RAM channels and faster DRAM sticks. (Fyi GPUs have faster DRAM)
From code standpoint you need to do more work per byte read or written, this translates to being cache friendly, you need to chain multiple operations/transformations per iteration instead of using multiple sequential parallel_for loops.
Writing more Cache friendly code can be done using C++20 ranges to construct data processing pipelines instead of doing multiple raw loops, you can even process the data as it is being read from the file instead of saving it to an intermediate vector, tbb even has an example of processing data in parallel as it is read from a file
It is also recommended that you do that pipeline in batches of small size like 8 to 1024 elements to use simd without invalidating the L1 cache.
